# How can I customize the error response in Web API with .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET Core 2.2 with Web API. I have created one class, i.e., as below:

```csharp
public class NotificationRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirebaseToken { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string OS { get; set; }

    public int StoreId { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above class I have created one method. Now I want to return a custom object, but it's returning its own object.
API method is:

```csharp
public ActionResult<bool> UpdateFirebaseToken(NotificationRequestModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(FormatOutput(ModelState.Values));
    }
    var result = _notificationService.InsertOrUpdateFirebaseToken(model);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Here `FormatOutput` method is format the output.

```csharp
protected Base FormatOutput(object input, int code = 0, string message = "", string[] details = null)
{
    Base baseResult = new Base();
    baseResult.Status = code;
    baseResult.Error = message;
    baseResult.TimeStamp = CommonHelper.CurrentTimeStamp;
    baseResult.Code = code;
    baseResult.Details = details;
    baseResult.Message = message; //Enum.Parse<APIResponseMessageEnum>(code.ToString(), true); // (enum of code get value from language)
    return baseResult;
}
```

But the issue is it returns:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "DeviceId": [
      "The DeviceId field is required."
    ]
  },
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "80000049-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

I want to customize this error with my model. I need error message and details from return output and passed it to my model. How can I do that? I had try to debug my code and found that breakpoint on API method is not calling. So I can't handle my custom method. Is there any solution? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Chris analyzed, your issue is caused by [Automatic HTTP 400
responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#automatic-http-400-responses).

For the quick solution, you could suppress this feature by

```csharp
services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

For an efficient way, you could follow the suggestion from Chris, like below:

```csharp
services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
            //options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
            {
                var modelState = actionContext.ModelState.Values;
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(FormatOutput(modelState));
            };
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

And, there isn't any need to define the code below any more in your action.

```csharp
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(FormatOutput(ModelState.Values));
}
```

Comment: For anyone using services.AddControllers the concept is the same:
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });

Answer (score 35):

When using a controller with the `ApiController` attribute applied, ASP.NET Core *automatically* handles model validation errors by returning a 400 Bad Request with `ModelState` as the response body. As such, your conditional testing `ModelState.IsValid` is essentially always false (and therefore not entered) because the only requests that will ever get this far are valid ones.

You could simply remove the `ApiController` attribute, but that removes a bunch of other beneficial stuff the attributes adds as well. The better option is to use a custom response factory:

```csharp
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState);
});
```

That's essentially what's happening by default, so you'd simply need to change the action provided there accordingly to customize it to your whims.