# How to replace ValidationProblemDetails with SCIM-compatible model validation error details in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, scim2

ASP.NET Core 3.1 is taking POSTed JSON (for creating a user via SCIM v2 in my fledgling Web API) and model-binding it to my C# request-data class `CreateUserRequest` like a champ.  And it produces nice ProblemDetails-based errors if there is an error in the JSON.

E.g. if the user's last name (aka family name) is missing (which it shouldn't be because I `[Require]` that property) then the response JSON is:-

```
{
  "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|dbd3da85-4991c45298582047.",
  "errors": {
    "Name.LastName": [
      "The LastName field is required.",
      "The field LastName must be a string with a minimum length of 1 and a maximum length of 100."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the result of `ValidationProblemDetails` and it's good for most purposes, but unfortunately it's not good for SCIM, which requires a different JSON format, [described here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#page-67).

E.g. SCIM errors look something like this:-

```
   {
     "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],
     "scimType":"mutability"
     "detail":"Attribute 'id' is readOnly",
     "status": "400"
   }
```

How to replace `ProblemDetails` and `ValidationProblemDetails` with something else (in this case something SCIM-compatible) in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API?

Comment: [How can I customize the error response in Web API with .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942192/how-can-i-customize-the-error-response-in-web-api-with-net-core)

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski  I was searching SO mainly for "problemdetails" etc. and so missed that link.  I also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145243/how-do-i-customize-asp-net-core-model-binding-errors

Comment: Chris Pratt is the one who has discovered the magic formula: set your own `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`.  [Microsoft docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-failure-error-response)