# Net Core Replace 400 Error with 200 response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to replace this 400 error as show below

```
{
  "errors": {
    "longId": [
      "Input string '123abc' is not a valid number. Path 'longId', line 5, position 21."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|a3b68bba-4ef8acafa70b702c."
}
```

To a customized error with the error code 200?
Example:

```
{
  "isSuccess": false,
  "message": "POST request failed. Please try again."
}
```

The code is something like this:

```
public class APostRequestModel 
{
  public int intId { get; set; }
  public long longId { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> APostRequest([FromBody] APostRequestModel aPostRequestModel)
{
  try
  {
     //some code here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     //some code here
  }
}
```

My request is as below:

```
{
   "intId": 123,
   "longId": 123abc
}
```

Comment: Although this question: [How can I customize the error response in Web API with .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942192/how-can-i-customize-the-error-response-in-web-api-with-net-core) returns Bad Request response, but the answers are the way to customize the model state (when fail) response.

Comment: Hi @Zorev Gnoz, you can modify the response by yourself, just use `return OK(new{isSuccess=false,message="xxxx"})` in your action when `ModelState.IsValid` is false. Did you use ASP.NET Core web api and it even does not get into your action then return the Bad Request error? If though, I think you can remove `[ApiController]` or set `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter ` true. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977547/11398810

Answer (score 0):

You can define below class as your response:

```
public class ApiResponseDto
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public dynamic Result { get; set; }
        public ApiResponseDto()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            Message = Messages.Success;
        }

        public ApiResponseDto(int httpStatusCode, string message, object result)
        {
            StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
            Message = message;
            Result = result;
        }
    }
    
public async Task<ApiResponseDto> APostRequest([FromBody] APostRequestModel aPostRequestModel)
{
  ApiResponseDto response = new ApiResponseDto();
  try
  {
     //some code here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     //some code here
  }
   return response;
}
```